# will mutex lock guarantee mem sync?

Tags: go

in goroutine A, I do this

```
mu.Lock()
n++
mu.UnLock()
```

can I see the changed n in goroutine B immediately?
in other word, will mutex guarantee memory sync
and in goroutine B

```
fmt.Println(n)
```

Comment: Yes. No. That‘s not how this works.

Comment: There is no concept of immediately in concurrency. Each thread of execution is on its own, independent timeline. They don't share points in time, so there is no "immediately".

Comment: I mean will write n to memory from cpu cache while mu.Unlock() done

Comment: CPU cache coherency is controlled by hardware, and not relevant to what each goroutine sees. As long as both goroutines are properly synchronized, then yes, the write will be visible. Since your goroutine B is unsynchronized you have a data race and no result is defined. All guarantees made by the language are specified here: https://golang.org/ref/mem

Answer (score -1):

If immediately means after the `mu.Unlock()` then yes, but keep in mind, that before reading value you should also acquire the lock. For instance, in a multiprocessor (multicore) system, each core has its own cache, and there may be situations when variable values in different core's caches are different.

For this specific situation of a single int variable perhaps using `"sync/atomic"` package is more beneficial. To update use `atomic.AddUint64(&n, 1)` and to read `atomic.LoadUint64(&n)`

If the struct of interest is `map` then you could use `sync.Map` with embedded RWMutex. RWMutex exposes different locks for update (`m.Lock()`) and read (`m.RLock()`).  And you could have safe parallel reads and after `m.RUnlock()` sequential updates.

Comment: I'm not going to resolve data race problem, I just want to know that will gorountine A sync n from cache to memory while mu.UnLock() done